# facebook interstitialad does not display close button in android app

Tags: android, facebook, ads

For some reason facebook interstitialad does not display close button in my android app. I am followed all the steps from: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android/interstitial

However, using back button it does close the ad correctly. But I need to have close button displayed, any help?

First image:
[image: Image 1]

Second Image:
[image: Image 2]

Following is code which is responsible for this AD:

```
public class MyActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
        SearchView.OnSuggestionListener, InterstitialAdListener {

    private InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    boolean adDismissed;

    private void loadInterstitialAd() {
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this, "my_id");
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(this);
        interstitialAd.loadAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
        // Ad is loaded and ready to be displayed
        // You can now display the full screen add using this code:
        interstitialAd.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        adDismissed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Ad ad, AdError error) {
        // Ad failed to load
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(!adDismissed)
            loadInterstitialAd();
    }   
}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: when does this `loadInterstitialAd()` function get called ?

Comment: in `onStart()` function

Comment: I think this is one of the ads that have a custom button to close it. I guess in this case the "NO" buttons will close the ads.